# JavaScript function crashes every time it's run

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this really fantastic game in JavaScript but a part of the function I just wrote crashes every time it's run.

So I'm wondering, is it just to much to run in a for loop or have I made a syntax error somewhere?

Here's the code; it's taken from a function but this is the part that makes it crash.

```
for (zloop=min_houses_per_block; zloop<(house_number+1); zloop++)
{
    if (zloop>0)
    {
        city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop].width =
                (min_house_width+(((max_house_width-min_house_width)/house_width_slots)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*house_width_slots))));

        city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop].height =
                (min_house_height+(((max_house_height-min_house_height)/house_height_slots)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*house_height_slots))));

        if (zloop=1)
        {
            x_number=(block_width-(house_threshold*2))-city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop].width;
            min_house_x=house_threshold
            city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop].x =
                    (min_house_x+(((x_number)/house_x_slots)*(Math.floor(Math.random()*house_x_slots))));
        }

        city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop].x=6000;
        city_block_array[0][0].house_array[1].x=6000;
    }
}
```

Without the `if (zloop=1)` part it runs fine.

Comment: Surely that could be simplified ..

Comment: It's JavaScript telling you to indent your code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean to say `if (zloop==1)`

Comment: i just broke my nose.... from facepalming myself so hard; I'm pathetic hahaha thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Your error is most likely this line:

```
if (zloop = 1) {
```

This sets `zloop` to `1`. You want to compare `zloop` to `1`, so use `zloop == 1`.

Also, try to trim down on the line length. You can use some more descriptive variables:

```
for (var zloop = min_houses_per_block; zloop < (house_number + 1); zloop++) {
  var house = city_block_array[first][second].house_array[zloop];

  if (zloop > 0) {
    house.width = (min_house_width + (((max_house_width - min_house_width) / house_width_slots) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * house_width_slots))));
    house.height = (min_house_height + (((max_house_height - min_house_height) / house_height_slots) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * house_height_slots))));

    if (zloop == 1) {
      x_number = (block_width - (house_threshold * 2)) - house.width;
      house.x = (house_threshold + (((x_number) / house_x_slots) * (Math.floor(Math.random() * house_x_slots))));
    } else {
      city_block_array[0][0].house_array[1].x = 6000;
      house.x = 6000;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (zloop=1)
```

Did you mean

```
if (zloop == 1)
```

= is an assignment
== is a comparison